# How can I fix Deja Dup hanging on restore?

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-one, backup, restore, deja-dup

I messed up with GIT and did hard reset (accidentally) and my effort to cancel it (from CL IDE) failed so my code is gone. Thank God today Deja Dup did a backup (although it did not finish as I told to go on later). So I tried to restore from Ubuntu one and it shows me the dates and I select today then it checks things and start the restore and hangs there.

It presents no error, no message just restoring. I dont know what to do. The dates are not found in Ubuntu one so I don't know where does this Deja Dup get the from. I don't know what to do as for now

[image: Selecting date]

[image: enter Restoring and hangs here]

Ubuntu one shot is this (No 18/07/2013)
[image: Ubuntu one]

Comment: If you have a lot of incremental backups it may take some time to restore your files. Are you sure it really hangs (ex: after one hour it is in the same state)?

Comment: Well let me mark my time and give it single hour untouched!

Comment: I can confirm it hangs. It does not go anywhere. And the device its connected is not having much (see shot above)

Comment: @Salem please make that an answer so that I accept it. It did not hang but rather it restored the data. It needed two hours of patience! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well As Salem said the Deja-Dup wa running fine and its perfectly normal for it to not give message of progress for very long time (at least it could say scanning but it is note coded to do so). So after being patient for two hours (Actually I left the computer on and started doing something else) I found the restoration done.

I will see if I can file feature request to add verbose mode so that user knows what is going on!